# How to make a menu and submenu in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to display a menu on my page with options like File, Edit, View, etc you would find in a Word document and when you click on the main menu item (File for example), a dropdown pops up with submenu options. I thought this was a basic behavior a lot of the UIs have but I am failing to find examples of doing this via AngularJS. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Angular UI bootstrap has support for everything BESIDES dropdowns from what I remember.  Try googling angular dropdown button

Answer (score 1):

Angular doesn't have any widgets for this built-in. You can either pull in jQuery plug-in or use something like Bootstrap to achieve this.

This example assumes you're using bootstrap 2.3.2 and have already created the functions in the controller:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">File <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#" ng-click="new()">New</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" ng-click="open()">Open</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" ng-click="save()">Save</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" ng-click="close()">Close</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[Bootstrap 2.3.2](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#navs)